# Unable to get userid using codeigniter REST API

Tags: php, mysql, rest, codeigniter

I want to register a form after login. The registration form includes 3 filed two of them are inserted through form and one is `userid` which is the login user's `userid`. when I try to get the user id the form is not submitted

```
 public function clinic_post()
{

    $authUser = $this->authUser();

    $area=$this->post('arae');

    $locality=$this->post('locality');

    $add=array('area'=>$area,
        'locality'=>$locality,
        id=>$authUser['id']);

    $this->load->model('ApiModel');
    $this->ApiModel->insert($add);  
}
```

Comment: dump this `$authUser` and see whether it's empty or not

Comment: $authUser is not empty i can get id in another function. i use the same method for this, but it is not working

Comment: add the code of method authUser() and the model also.

Comment: its not working